# How to Fix an Error in Phoenix Application with Addict for User Authentication

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm implementing user authentication with Addict in a Phoenix application as per the instructions at https://github.com/trenpixster/addict.

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
[error] #PID<0.549.0> running Myapp.Endpoint terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: GET /register
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Myapp.Addict.AddictController.init/1 is undefined (module Myapp.Addict.AddictController is not available)
        Myapp.Addict.AddictController.init(:register)
        (myapp) web/router.ex:1: anonymous fn/1 in Myapp.Router.match_route/4
        (myapp) lib/phoenix/router.ex:261: Myapp.Router.dispatch/2
        (myapp) web/router.ex:1: Myapp.Router.do_call/2
        (myapp) lib/myapp/endpoint.ex:1: Myapp.Endpoint.phoenix_pipeline/1
        (myapp) lib/plug/debugger.ex:123: Myapp.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
        (myapp) lib/myapp/endpoint.ex:1: Myapp.Endpoint.call/2
        (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:15: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4
        (cowboy) /Users/development/Desktop/myapp/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
```

Here is my `web/router.ex` file:

```
defmodule Myapp.Router do
  use Myapp.Web, :router

  use Addict.RoutesHelper

  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_flash
    plug :protect_from_forgery
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
  end

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end

  scope "/", Myapp do
    pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

    get "/", PageController, :index
    get "/about", PageController, :about 
    get "/thanks", PageController, :thanks
    resources "/projects", ProjectController

    addict :routes
  end

  # Other scopes may use custom stacks.
  # scope "/api", Myapp do
  #   pipe_through :api
  # end
end
```

Why is this error happening and how can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the complete error message including the stacktrace?

Comment: Can you also post the source of your router (`web/router.ex`)?

Comment: Source of web/router.ex posted as well :)

Comment: What if you remove `addict :routes` from there and add another scope (after the current scope ends) like this: `scope "/" do addict(:routes) end`? (That namespace module might be causing this.)

Comment: That does it. Post as an answer and I'll accept - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing a module alias to `scope` will prepend that module to all the controllers of all the routes defined within, including `addict` routes, which will make them point to the wrong controller (`Myapp.Addict.AddictController` instead of `Addict.AddictController`). You can move `addict :routes` into another scope without the alias module to fix this:

```
scope "/", Myapp do
  pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

  get "/", PageController, :index
  get "/about", PageController, :about 
  get "/thanks", PageController, :thanks
  resources "/projects", ProjectController
end

scope "/" do
  addict :routes
end
```